# ado.net combine two rows into 1

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I'm working on a project that will combine a couple of sharepoint listitemcollections. It's basically to bring together three sharepoint lists.

I've already gotten my three sharepoint queries to return my proper results and im using the .GetDataTable() method to generate my objects for LINQ joins.

Below is my code. I may be approaching this wrong but if there is a way I can return one data row that has all three objects combined is all I need.

```
DataTable dtContracts = _contractList.GetDataTable();
        DataTable dtCustomer = _customerList.GetDataTable();

        var joined = from contracts in dtContracts.AsEnumerable()
                           join customers in dtCustomer.AsEnumerable()
                           on contracts.Field<String>("ContractNumber")
                           equals customers.Field<String>("ContractNumber")
                           join SPListItem loans in _loanList
                           on contracts["ContractNumber"] equals loans["Contract_x0020_Number"] 
                           into JoinedContractLoans
                           from loans in JoinedContractLoans.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { contracts, customers,loans };
```

Comment: What's the question? I think your query should return list of objects that have all three objects in them.

Comment: svick, that is correct and that is what i'm getting. I think I am making this more complicated by trying to use loosely typed methods. Time to step back and reevaluate. Thank you everyone for taking the time to review.

Comment: @Marek, no, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) instance isn't that feasible because you don't have direct access to [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.datarow.aspx) to create an instance; you'd have to create a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) that contains all the columns from the three disparate `DataTable` instances you have and then add the rows through the `DataTable`.

While this is certainly doable, it's a lot of extra work.

You could also create an anonymous/concrete type that has *all* the fields from the separate `DataTable` instances and populate instances of that, like so:

```
// Rest of query the same.
select new { 
    ContractNumber = contracts.Field<string>("ContractNumber")
    // All other contract fields.

    // All customer fields.

    // All loan fields.
};
```

If you are working with anonymous types, then this would be easy to maintain.  However, for a concrete class, it might be a little unwieldy.

That said, you're left with what you have now, creating an anonymous type which has references to the three data rows.  It's probably the easiest to maintain, assuming the code that's working with this is in the same method.

That said, if you had to pass this outside a method, I'd recommend having a strongly-typed [data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which you map the `DataRow` to and then pass back the collection of the three data transfer objects.

Of course, if you're going that route, then you should look at [LINQ-to-Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx), as this is essentially made for this purpose (it will probably simplify a lot of this code).